# Alternative to prepared statement when using AWS RDS proxy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, amazon-rds-proxy

It says in the documentation of RDS proxy that the connection is automaticaly pinned when the application uses a prepared statement:

> Prepared statements cause the proxy to pin the session. This rule applies whether the prepared statement uses SQL text or the binary protocol. (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/rds-proxy.html)

How am I supposed to protect my application against SQL injections while using RDS proxy?
I am using this service to make the connection with the database faster in my microservices so I want the connection to be reused.

Comment: Have you found out anymore information about this? I believe I am running into the exact same problem. I just setup an RDS proxy and it isn't helping at all because all of my database connections are session pinned. I presume it's because Knex uses prepared statements.

Comment: @lastmjs I decided to not use RDS proxy for now. I solved the connection time problem by increasing the memory of the lambda function. I found somewhere that you get more CPUs when you increase the memory

Comment: @ClémentBisaillon are you not running into performance issues when using lambdas to directly connect to your DB? I thought this was the reason why people used the proxy in the first place

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I used RDS Proxy for the Postgresql RDS. To connect to RDS Proxy I used gem 'pg' (project on ruby).

At first, I disabled some initial queries to the database when the connection establish (like set timezone and etc).

And the problem with a prepared statement. The rds proxy make the session pinned if it sees a query like below:

```
SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
```

So if rds proxy sees that query the session will be pinned. But if you make the query in that way the session will no be pinned:

```
SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
```

So when I change my library code a little bit I solved this problem. And also it will really help if you enable logs for the rds proxy (Advanced configuration). After enabling you can see why your session is pinned in the Cloud Watch Metrics.

Comment: do you have an example on how to use PG along with RDS Proxy?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to append `?binary_parameters=yes` or `&binary_parameters=yes` to the connection string.

i.e.

```
postgres://user:password@rds-proxy.proxy-dgi349gjv95j.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/db_name?binary_parameters=yes
```

and I saw a drop on the pinned `prepared_statements`.

I haven't followed that solution yet as I am still investigating if RDS proxy is still the best option for our use case.